# I have a problem with starting expo on my local machine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-native

> error Invalid regular expression:
>   /(.*\__fixtures__\.*|node_modules[\]react[\]dist[\].*|website\node_modules\.*|heapCapture\bundle.js|.*\__tests__\.*)$/:
>   Unterminated character class. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more
>   details.

Metro Bundler process exited with code 1

How can I fix that problem?

Comment: What version of Node are you running?

Comment: And what does `expo start --verbose` say?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your version of node.
If your current version is higher than the version 10 LTS please try to downgrade.
I had the same issue and then I had to change it and the thing works fine.